# Bootstrap responsive table doesn't work with Ember.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I'm new to Bootstrap and Ember. I'm trying to generate a responsive table using Ember.js.
The problem is that when my application is running if I change the browswer's size to an small one, I don't see the horizontal scroll at the table as expected.
However if I save the web page and open it from disk, then it works ok. Very odd :)
I'm pasting my page code here in case it helps. It's a simple example I'm using to learn.
Thanks in advance.
Cheers!!
Gonzalo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

      <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link href="libs/bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    </head>
    <body>
      <script type="text/x-handlebars">
        <h2>Registro de llamadas</h2>

        {{outlet}}
      </script>

      <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">

      <div class="container">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table">
              <th>
                  Número
              </th>
              <th>
                  Nombre
              </th>
              <th>
                  Asunto
              </th>   
              {{#each item in model}}                  
              <tr>
                  <td>
                    {{#link-to 'editarLlamada' item}}Editar{{/link-to}}
                  </td>
                  <td> 
                      {{item.number}}
                  </td>              
                  <td> 
                      {{item.name}}
                  </td>
                  <td> 
                      {{item.subject}}
                  </td>              
              </tr>
              {{/each}}
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button {{action 'nuevallamada'}}>Nueva llamada</button>  

      </script>

      <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="nuevallamada">
             <div class='container'>
                  <p>Acá ingreso la nueva llamada</p>
               {{input type="text" value=number}}
               {{input type="text" value=name}}
               {{input type="text" value=subject}}

                 <button {{action 'guardarllamada'}}>Guardar</button>   
             </div>     
      </script>

      <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
      <script src="libs/bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


      <!-- <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> -->
      <script src="js/libs/ember-template-compiler-1.10.0.js"></script>
      <script src="js/libs/ember-1.10.0.debug.js"></script>
      <script src="js/libs/ember-data.js"></script>


      <script src="js/app.js"></script>
      <script src="js/controllers/nuevallamada-controller.js"></script>
      <script src="js/routes/nuevallamada-route.js"></script>
      <script src="js/routes/editarllamada-route.js"></script>
      <script src="js/routes/index-route.js"></script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to bootstrap, the table structure should be like below

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>header1</th>
        <th>header2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    </tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>value 1</td>
        <td>value 2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

For more reference follow [Bootstrap Responsive Table](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive)